# In a responsive layout, how would css style if column is wider than 400px?

Tags: css, responsive

We can style responsively according to the viewport width, but I want to style depending on the column width.

In my layout, if the column is wider than 400px, the text should be bigger.

(I cannot control how many columns there will be in the row. The Wordpress admin will choose that).

Comment: You need javascript to do that. can't be done with css

Comment: Sounds like a job for [container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries). Unfortunately, they're not available yet, except behind an experimental flag in Chromium-based browsers.